# Specifying a difference in differences model with two treatment groups

Tags: econometrics, multicollinearity, difference-in-difference

I have seen some other questions very similar to this, but it's not clear to me if any of the answers appear to my scenario. Basically, I have three groups that are democrat, republican and independent, and we want to find how they change their portfolio when a particular party is in power.

I'm wondering how do I go about specifying a difference in differences in model in this case. Specifically, I am wondering if this model works:

$$Y = \alpha + \delta Party + \beta_1 DEM + \beta_2 REP +\gamma_0 IND*Party+\gamma_1 DEM*Party + \gamma_2 REP*Party+ \varepsilon$$
where $IND$ is the control group. My current understanding is that I can interpret the coefficients as follows:

Effect of party on independents: $\delta + \gamma_0$

Effect of party on democrats: $\delta+ \gamma_1$

Effect of party on republicans: $\delta+ \gamma_2$,

so to calculate the additional effect on democrats, for example, we would compute $\gamma_1 - \gamma_0$. Is this interpretation correct?

Moreover, I am concerned about multicollinearity with respect to the interaction terms. Is there another (simpler?) way to specify this model? What if I omitted the constant and included an $IND$ dummy?

Comment: Because you are including *interactions* between indicator variables, you will probably want to go with [effect coding](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-effect-coding/) to avoid inducing heteroscedasticity, and thus biasing your estimates.